# Protractor e2e test has error : TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqxGrid'

Tags: angularjs, protractor, jqxgrid

I am writing AngularJS e2e testcases using Protractor. 
My Applciation uses jqxGrid(from jqxWidgets). In my testcase i need to test size of jqxGrid which in js is done by

```
gridSelector.jqxGrid('getrows').length
```

Testcase is as

```
it('should check grid size', function() {
  var grid = browser.findElement(by.id('jqxoutbox'));
  grid.findElements( by.css('div:nth-child(2) > div')).then(function(results){
      console.log(results[0].jqxGrid('getrows').length);
  });
});
```

Now in my testcase i can find the gridSelector id but can not execute jqxGrid function to find size.

```
StackTrace : 
Failures:

  1) e2e: main should have grid element
         Message:
                TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqxGrid'
         Stacktrace:
                TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqxGrid'
```

Please provide any help on how can i access my jqxGrid functions in my testcase.